# NextJs 13 on demand revalidation 308 Api Error

Tags: next.js, types, interrupt, next.js13

Just started a next 13 app and i am trying to create on demand revalidation endpoint but it keeps giving me the following error

`Error: Invalid response 308 at DevServer.revalidate`

```
my app dir is 
   /app
     /[locale]
       /(content)
         pages.tsx
   /pages 
     /api
       revalidation.ts
```

revalidation.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(
  resquest: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (resquest.query.secret !== process.env.NEXT_REVALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    return response.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token.' });
  }

  const { path } = resquest.query;

  // return response.status(200).json({ revalidated: path });
  await response.revalidate(path as string);

  return response.status(200).json({ revalidated: true });
}
```

I am passing in the path correctly i think but i have a feeling it's todo with locales ? Has anyone else had this before? Been stuck on it all night haha

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the 308 error by changing `.../api/revalidate` to `.../api/revalidate/`.